# TYPO3 fileadmin permission denied when created by ftp

Tags: permissions, typo3

is there any possibility to change the permission when a folder in fileadmin is created per ftp and now you cannot copy a file into this folder?
TYPO3 is version 8.7

Greeting
Volker

Answer (score 1):

You will have 3 Options:

- Create the folder with a user that is in apache/nginx/php group, respectively dont use the FTP-Root user on creation.
- Connect via FTP and fix the permission of the folder.
- Connect via SSH and fix the permission in terminal context.

Regards 
Ribase

Comment: As addition: On mostly shared hostings the user of apache is different from the user of the ftp. So if the ftp create an folder without permission for group or other to execute, the webserver is not allowed to change into this directory. So the group and/or other need to have the read and execute permissions to this directory and at least the read permission to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not TYPO3 specific. It's an unix problem.
or better: you need to understand rights management on unix systems.

there are three levels: owner, group, everyone
for each level you can define the possible rights (read, write, execute)
in octal notation this matches exact the bits of coding

```
rwxrwxrwx
||||||+++-- everyone
|||+++----- group
+++-------- owner
```

Also each file holds an owner and a group.

Folders are a special kind of files which need execution rights to see the content (list of files).

Then there are default bits that are set if a file (or folder) is generated. These bits can be configured with the `umask` command - or the program you create the file. with TYPO3 you can define it in the install tool.
Maybe your FTP program has similar configuration.

Depending whether your FTP-user and the PHP/Apache-User are identical, share one group or have nothing in common you need to set the bits for each file to grant access each other.
be aware: independent from your BE-user which you use for login in TYPO3 BE, any file action in the BE (or FE) is done with the apache/PHP user, which probably is not your FTP user.

In a shell you have the commands `chmod` to change the assess bits and `chown` to change the owner and group of a file. (hint: `chgrp` will only change the default group assigned to new files)

If you do not have the writing rights for folder and file you can not change any rights of a file. Especially not the right to modify a file (remember: folders are files).

The best option to modify the rights is to use the same user than the file was created (as an owner you have the most rights).
Second best is to be `root`. Root is allowed to do anything, but therefore you should avoid being root, as you also can destroy anything.